# Subdomain setup for Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns, express-vhost

I setup a Heroku app with vhost for subdomain handling. The app stopped responding to the custom domain originally assigned to it but the main Heroku app is live and working however, the subdomain link does not work for heroku. Please how can I fix this issue. app-name.herokuapp.com works. subdomain.app-name.herokuapp.com does not work. Also, customdomain.xyz does not work too.

Answer (score 1):

All apps deployed on heroku actually are on subdomain of `herokuapp.com` so you can't create a subdomain for your app while using `herokuapp.com` for this you have to set custom domain, please follow the [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-subdomains) to check how to set up custom domain.